# Will Twilio ignore empty tags when sending a response?

Tags: asp.net, xml-serialization, twilio

I am implementing a solution using ASP.NET web services with XML serialization.

I would like to know if Twilio ignores empty xml tags included in the response?

For example;

```
<gather>
   Blah blah blah...
</gather>
<redirect/> // Would this tag be ignored and if no response from the caller, Twilio hangs up?
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the REDIRECT will only be executed when there is no response from the caller. A response will skip the REDIRECT.

Interestingly, since the URL is empty and relative paths are supported, I think Twilio would redirect you to the same URL... creating a potential loop.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

If there is no input from the user during the `<Gather>`, Twilio will continue to process the next verb in the TwiML document which in your case means the `<Redirect>` verb.

Once there are no more verbs for Twilio to process, we will terminate the call.

Hope that helps.